# Need to extract child tag values based on a condition

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Below  is the inpt. I need to extract b2,b3,b4 values where b1=555. there can be more than 3 blocks of  as well. Currently trying to iterate through each block, any other robust way to do this

```
    <a>
    <b1>111</b>
     <b2>222</b>
    <b3>333</b>
    <b4>444</b>
   </a>
    <a>
     <b1>555</b>
     <b2>666</b>
     <b3>777</b>
     <b4>888</b>
   </a>
    <a>
    <b1>999</b>
     <b2>000</b>
     <b3>122</b>
     <b4>167</b>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make your selection criteria pick all < b1 > where the value is 555.

Something like this:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <!-- Select all a element that have a b1 element who's value is 555 -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//a[./b1=555]" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="a">
      b1=<xsl:value-of select="b1"/>
      b2=<xsl:value-of select="b2"/>
      b3=<xsl:value-of select="b3"/>
      b4=<xsl:value-of select="b4"/>     
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: I printed the b1 value so show that it was the correct set of values for illustration. Also you should use a apply template again and have a different template for each type b2 b3 b4, so that you can have separate transformation for each if there transformations are very different from each other.

This stylesheet run against your sample produces:

```
 b1=555
 b2=666
 b3=777
 b4=888
```